# Get key from an object in an array in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = ({
        childData: [],
        test: []
    });
}

componentDidMount() {
    let userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    firebase.database().ref('poolog/' + userId).on('value', (snapshot) => {
       let test = [];
       snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
          let childKey = childSnapshot.key;
          test.push(snapshot.val());
        });
        this.setState({childData: test});
        // console.log(this.state.childData);
    });
```

I use this function in the return method of React.

```
 {this.state.childData.map((item, key) =>
     <View key={key}>
        {console.log(Object.values(item) + 'test')}
        <Text>{Object.keys(item)}</Text>
        {Object.values(item).map((value, index) =>
          <View></View>
        )}
     </View>
  )}
```

I have a question, I only want a specific value, `Object.values(item)` gives all the values, and when I use `Object.values(item[key])` or `Object.values(item[0])` I get:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(item[0]')
>   or
>   TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(item[key]')

And `{console.log(Object.values(item) + 'test')}` gives the following output:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]test
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]test
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]test
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]test
```

How can I fix this, that I only get a specific object from this.

```
<Text>Object.values(item)</Text>
```

gives:

```
    10-1-201910-5-2019-10-9-2019-9-5-2019
    10-1-201910-5-2019-10-9-2019-9-5-2019
    10-1-201910-5-2019-10-9-2019-9-5-2019
    10-1-201910-5-2019-10-9-2019-9-5-2019
```

Comment: You can fix the `[object Object]` issue with `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Object.values(myObject) will give you an array of all the values in that object.

for instance: `Object.values({ one: 1, two: 2 })[1] === 2 `

Comment: @JJNL77 can show the json structure you are working with ?

Answer (score 5):

pls refer below examples...

```
const obj1 = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 25,
  c: ['apple', 'mango']
};

console.log(Object.values(obj1));  // Array ['hello', 25, Array ['apple', 'mango']]
console.log(Object.keys(obj1));  // Array ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

so in your case,
if you use like `Object.values(item)` // **item** must be object
if you use like `Object.values(item[key])` // **item[key]** must be object
if you use like `Object.values(item[0])` // **item[0]** must be object

hence whatever inside **Object.values()** or **Object.keys()** must be **object**

so `item[key]` or `item[0]` must be evaluate to object
in your code it evaluates to `undefined` so only below errors are occur

**TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating Object.keys(item[key]))**
**TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating Object.keys(item[0]))**

as per your need, now you need to use like one of below:

- `Object.values(item)[0]` or `Object.values(item)[1]` (static)
- `Object.values(item).filter((val,ind) => {})` (condition based)
- `Object.values(item).map((val,ind) => {})` (if you want to use all)

Hope this detailed explanation helps you.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the keys of a particular object with object.keys

The **Object.keys()** method returns an array of a given object's own property names, in the same order as we get with a normal loop.

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};

console.log(Object.keys(object1));
// expected output: Array ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use lodash: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get

```
const obj1 = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 25,
  c: ['apple', 'mango']
};

_.get(obj1, 'a');
// => 'hello'

_.get(obj1, 'c[0]');
// => 'apple'

_.get(obj1, 'a.b.c', 'default');
// => 'default'
```